# Where to find wolves

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm having trouble finding wolves. I saw a question written a few years ago that had a "protip" stating to set out some torches in a forest biome, kill all the bad guys, and wolves would be found in about 10 minutes. This didn't work for me. Neither has wandering around aimlessly holding a bone. I've heard that wolves are less likely to spawn in 1.8? Anyone have any other tips? I really want a pack of tamed wolves for my base. I've searched birch forests, forests, taiga, mega taiga...no luck!

Answer (score 3):

From *Minecraft Wiki*:

> Wolves spawn only in Forest, Taiga, Mega Taiga, Cold Taiga, and Cold Taiga M biomes.

If you have difficulties finding them in these biomes, then blame your luck. Sorry.